# Why does the Bash read command return without any input?

Tags: bash, unix, stdin

I have a Bash script `foo` that accepts a list of words on STDIN. The script should read the words into an array, then ask for user input:

```
while IFS= read -r; do
  words+=( "$REPLY" )
done

read -r ans -p "Do stuff? [Yn] "
echo "ans: |$ans|"
```

The problem is, Bash immediate reads an empty string into the `ans` variable, without waiting for actual user input. That is, I get the following output (with no prompt or delay):

```
$ cat words.txt | foo
ans: ||
```

Since everything piped into STDIN has already been consumed by the first `read` call, why does the second `read` call return without actually reading anything?

Comment: Returning without reading anything is how your `while` loop terminates in the first place: `read` has a non-zero exit status when there is no (complete) line to read.

Comment: Since everything piped into STDIN has already been consumed by the first `read` call, there is nothing left for the second `read` call to read!

Comment: @WilliamPursell - What I meant by this was, what's the difference between this case and a `read` call to the terminal (without input redirection)? In a terminal `read` call, there's nothing to read either, until I type something and press enter. So why does `read` wait for my input on that call and not here?

Comment: Because here, the input stream is already closed.  When you have stdin connected to a tty, the file descriptor stays open until you type ^d (or whatever the keystroke is for your platform).  (And in that case, the first while loop would never terminate)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: If you type ^D while providing interactive input to the `while` loop, it _does_ terminate (_instantly_, if ^D is pressed at the _start_ of the line, and on the _second_ ^D press otherwise). ^D (possibly twice) causes `read` to report exit code `1`, which exits the `while` loop, but stdin stays open, and the next `read` command works as intended.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for pointing that out!  Yes, ^d does not close stdin.  ^d causes the tty to flush its input buffer, which (if empty) causes `read` (the system call) to return 0 which in turn makes `read` (the bash builtin) return 0.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks for the feedback; I've added a more elaborate version of your comment as a footnote to my answer (as an aside: you meant "makes `read` (the bash builtin) return [set exit code to] _1_", not 0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging by your symptoms, it looks like **you've *redirected stdin*** to provide the list of words to the `while` loop either via an input file (`foo < file`) or via a pipeline (`... | foo`).

If so, **your second `read` command won't automatically switch back to reading from the *terminal***; it is still reading from whatever stdin was redirected to, and if that input has been consumed (which is exactly what your `while` loop does, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in a comment), `read` reads nothing, and returns with exit code `1` (which is what terminated the `while` loop to begin with).

If you explicitly want the second `read` command to **get user input from the *terminal***, use:

```
read -r -p "Do stuff? [Yn] " ans </dev/tty
```

Note:

- **Stdin redirected from a (finite) *file*** (or pipeline or process substitution with finite output) is a *finite* resource that **eventually reports an EOF condition** once all input has been consumed:

  - `read` translates the EOF condition into exit code `1`, causing the `while` loop to exit:

    - Specifically, if `read` cannot read *any* more characters, it assigns the *null string* (empty string) to the specified variable(s) (or `$REPLY` if none were specified), and sets the exit code to `1`.
      Note: `read` may set exit code `1` even when it *does* read characters (and stores them in the specified variable(s) / `$REPLY`), namely if the input ends *without a delimiter*; the delimiter is `\n` by default, otherwise the delimiter explicitly specified with `-d`.
  - Once all input has been consumed, ***subsequent* `read` commands cannot read anything anymore** (the EOF condition persists, and the behavior is as described above).
- **By contrast, *interactive* stdin input from a *terminal*** is ***potentially infinite***: additional data is provided by whatever the user types interactively whenever stdin input is requested.

  - The way to ***simulate* an EOF condition** during **interactive *multiline* input** (i.e, to **terminate an input *loop***) is to press <kbd>^D</kbd> (<kbd>Control-D</kbd>):

    - When <kbd>^D</kbd> is pressed *once* at the *very start of a line*, `read` returns without reading anything and sets the exit code to `1`, just as if EOF had been encountered.

      - In other words: **the way to terminate unbounded interactive input in a loop is to press <kbd>^D</kbd> *after* having *submitted* the last line of input.**
    - By contrast, in the *interior* of an input line, pressing <kbd>^D</kbd> *twice* is needed to stop reading and set the exit code to `1`, but note that the line typed so far *is saved* to the target variable(s) / `$REPLY`.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Since **the stdin input stream wasn't actually *closed***, **subsequent `read` commands work normally** and continue to solicit interactive user input.
  - Caveat: **If you press <kbd>^D</kbd> at the *shell*'s prompt** (as opposed to while a *running program* is requesting input), **you'll terminate the shell itself.**

---

P.S.:

There is one ***incidental* error in the question**:

- The second `read` command must place operand `ans` (the name of the variable to store the input in) *after all options* in order to work syntactically: `read -r -p "Do stuff? [Yn] " ans`

---

<sup>[1] As [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) points out in a comment on the question: <kbd>^D</kbd> causes the `read(2)` system call to return with whatever is in the buffer at that point; the direct value returned is the *count of characters read*.

A count of `0` is how the EOF condition is signaled, and Bash's `read` translates that into exit code `1`, causing termination of the loop.

Thus, pressing <kbd>^D</kbd> at the start of a line, when the input buffer is empty, exits the loop immediately.

By contrast, if characters have already been typed on the line, then the *first* <kbd>^D</kbd> causes `read(2)` to return however many characters were typed so far, upon which Bash's `read` *reinvokes* `read(2)`, because the delimiter (a newline by default) hasn't been encountered yet.

An *immediately following second* <kbd>^D</kbd> then causes `read(2)` to return `0`, since no characters were typed, causing Bash's `read` to set exit code `1` and exit the loop.</sup>

Comment: Nice .I was wondering on what return value from `read` would `while` terminate. I got the answer already. :) The logic seems good with such loops, they really suck in a readability  perspective. What is happening behind the hood is not immediately clear. Like Chet Ramey said, *there are dark corners in the Bourne shell, and people use all of them.*

Comment: @sjsam: One of these dark corners is `read` returning exit code `1` for a line not terminated with a newline (`\n`), despite reading the value. Therefore, a `while` loop will not catch the last line of a file if it isn't newline-terminated.
The workaround: `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do ...`

Comment: Thank you @mklement0! Please note I've removed the `$word` typo in the read command in my original question, since it distracts from the real question. For reference, the original code read: `while IFS= read -r word; do words+=( "$REPLY" ); done`; as you pointed out, the value would be stored in `$word`, not in `$REPLY`, in this case.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "`read` reads nothing", does this mean it's seeing an EOF character? Otherwise, how does it know there's not more input coming?

Comment: @Sasgorilla: Thanks for the feedback; there is no EOF _character_, only an EOF _condition_; see if my substantial update helps.

Comment: @mklement0: Indeed. You are the wind beneath my wings.